# Using Modal in Bootstrap for Edit, Delete & Details Action

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a list of data and every data has an action of Edit, Delete, & Details. I used ajax for querying this data from the database. And what I wanted to do now is every time I click any of the button, the Modal will pop-up with the data.

This is my view:

```
var id_modal = item.switches_info_id;
<td>

                                @Ajax.ActionLink("Actions", "Transaction", new { id=item.switches_info_id},
                                   new AjaxOptions
                                   {
                                        HttpMethod = "Get",
                                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                        UpdateTargetId = "edit-div",
                                        }, new { @class= "link-list"})
                            </td>
                            <td>

                                <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit">
                                @Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "Edit", new { id=item.switches_info_id},
                                   new AjaxOptions
                                   {
                                        HttpMethod = "Get",
                                        UpdateTargetId = "Edit_Modal"+ item.switches_info_id,
                                        }, new { @class= "fa fa-edit fa-lg", id="id_attr"})&nbsp;&nbsp;||&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                </span>
                                <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Details">
                                @Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "Details", new { id=item.switches_info_id},
                                   new AjaxOptions
                                   {
                                        HttpMethod = "Get",
                                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                        UpdateTargetId = "edit-div",
                                        }, new { @class= "fa fa-plus-square fa-lg"})&nbsp;&nbsp;||&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                </span>
                                <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete">
                                @Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "Delete", new { id=item.switches_info_id},
                                   new AjaxOptions
                                   {
                                        HttpMethod = "Get",
                                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                        UpdateTargetId = "edit-div",
                                        }, new { @class= "fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"})
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal_Edit @id_modal" aria-hidden="true">@id_modal</button></td>
                        </tr>

                        <div class="modal fade" id="Edit_Modal @id_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Switch Info</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">Sample
                                        @Html.Action("Edit","Switch")
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    }
```

Above of this view, I put my code to call the modal function in bootstrap.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Switch Info</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @Html.Action("Edit","Switch")
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript that will add an attribute needed in bootstrap:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#id_attr').attr('data-toggle');
```

This is my code displaying the modal:

```
@model InSys.Models.Switches_vw
<script src="~/Scripts/telephones.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/datepicker.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Switch", FormMethod.Post)) {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)   
            @Html.Hidden("switches_info_id",Model.switches_info_id)
            @Html.Hidden("switch_transactions_id",Model.switch_transactions_id) 
            @Html.Hidden("sw_trans_type",Model.sw_trans_type)
            @Html.Hidden("sw_trans_by",Model.sw_trans_by)
            @Html.Hidden("sw_trans_date",Model.sw_trans_date)
            @Html.Hidden("sw_history_status",Model.sw_history_status)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.switches_info_id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.created_by) 
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.created_date)
      <table class="edit-table">
            <caption id="pr-table"><b> EDIT INFORMATION </b></caption>
            <tr>
                <td class="i_name">Brand: </td><td class="td">@Html.DropDownList("brand_id")</td>
                <td class="i_name">Model:</td> <td class="td"> @Html.DropDownList("model_id")</td>
                <td class="i_name">Supplier:</td><td class="td">@Html.DropDownList("sw_suppliers_id", String.Empty)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="i_name">No of Ports: </td><td class="td">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.sw_no_of_ports)</td>
                <td class="i_name">Serial Number:</td><td class="td">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.sw_serial_no)</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="i_name">Mac Address:</td> <td class="td"> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sw_mac_address)</td>
                <td class="i_name">IP Address: </td><td class="td">@Html.Editor("sw_ip_address")</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="i_name">Node Name:</td> <td class="td"> @Html.Editor("sw_node_name")</td>
                <td class="i_name">Location: </td><td class="td">@Html.Editor("sw_location")</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="i_name">Date Delivered:</td> <td class="td"> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sw_delivery_date)</td>
                <td class="i_name">End of Warranty: </td><td class="td">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.sw_warranty_end)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="i_name">POE:</td> <td class="td"> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sw_poe)</td>
                <td class="i_name">Active?</td><td class="td">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.is_active)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="i_name">Remarks: </td><td class="td">@Html.Editor("sw_remarks")</td>
            </tr>

        </table>

   <p class="save">
        @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "Switch", new { @class="button"})
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>     }
```

But, this code is not working. There is no modal will pop-up after I clicked the Edit button. How will I achieve this? Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the server is returning the info you require correctly? But the problem is just the modal not appearing? Could you include the code you used to display the modal?

Comment: The server returned the info, it's the modal function that does not triggered.

Comment: Are you sure that you have referenced all css files needed to run modal in bootstrap?? See an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NUCgp/5/)

Comment: Yes, I included all in my lay_out view. I've tried to run something has a modal also, then it works.